# Get ASN information from an IP in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ip

I'm currently trying to get the ASN number and name/description from an IP via Node.js, but I can't find any library that works/supports it. All I can find is geo-location which do not help me. Is there any way to do this that I am not aware of?

Edit: I'd like to mention I cannot use any 3rd party APIs.

Cheers

Comment: There's npm ip-to-asn but it uses a 3rd party API. Maxmind have a free DB called `GeoLite2-ASN` that you could use alternativelly

Comment: Alternative, you can use the free LITE ASN database https://lite.ip2location.com/database-asn